# Secrets Manager : GCP cost estimation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform, gcp-secrets-manager

I am in the process of configuring a Dataform workspace for ETL workloads and as part of the set up I have to integrate the Dataform workspace with git.
Now in order to do this I need to connect via https using a git token which I need to add to the GCP secrets manager and then expose to Dataform.
My concern is I am not sure how this works in the background in terms of the access operations and I wondering what is the best way to estimate the potential cost of this with regards to Dataform workloads.

I have looked at some examples in the docs but I am still confused as to how to estimate this.

Is it calculated like this :

- git commit = access operation
- dataform job run = access operation

I need to understand this so that I can properly estimate the cost in terms of how many potential access operation will I have on a monthly basis.

Comment: It depends on when your secrets are accessed. But, in any case, it will cost a few $ per month. You should have much more other bigger cost (like BigQuery cost!)

Comment: I want to understand how that works like what will count as an access operation in my case, does it happen with every git commit, every job run from the repo's code, with every instance of actually opening the remote repo in the browser etc. like I have no idea how many possible access operation this will lead to. The problem is I am dealing with business here and so I need to have a clear estimate of what this might cost even if it won't cost much.

Comment: I don't see any case where a commit will request a secret access. When you push, also. Except if you have a trigger that runs a pipeline which need your secret to perform operation. Because I don't know the details of your workload, I can't tell you the number of access exactly. But, I can guarrantee that won't be the major concern in your blling!

Comment: Do you think running a query (say on a schedule) counts as an operation ? Like when exactly does Dataform accesses the secret, when I initially set it up (like adding the secret to my git integration when I sync Dataform with remote git repo) or does it continually authenticate each time I want to run a query ? 
Thank you for the help by the way I can see also that the billing is very cheap even with 10000 operations but I am curious how this works in the background

Comment: By the way the secret is not part of any actual code but just the setting up of the git integration between the Dataform workspace and the remote git repository